# How Can I Keep My Novel Writing a Secret?

Tags: creative-writing, novel

What is the best way of keeping your novel writing a secret, without making people concerned that you are a loner? Because writing requires you to have solitude and to be mindful (I actually imaging scenes in my head before writing), how can I do this?

Also, if you tell someone you are writing, it may jinx the whole project, and cause you to abandon your project (especially if you are writing for the first time).

Any guidelines would be much appreciated.

Comment: Side Note - I love the feeling of spending hours alone with a handful of good songs, a computer, and the twisting gears in my mind. But remember not to do it too much because then you can get strung out, or so used to the feeling of being alone that you forget being social can actually be beneficial. And all the inspiration one can find for their story lies in the outside world, right?

Comment: Yes @Tasch. This my novel, historical fiction is based on what I've gleaned and internalized from my surroundings.

Comment: @ Tasch - I so know what you mean.  I've always wanted to write a novel but haven't been able to set the atmosphere to do so.  I recently moved and with the new setup, I throw my writing music playlist, sit at the computer and write now.  Before I know it, a few hours go by.

Comment: @ Marium - my suggestion - stay single. :-)   I have no problems having to keep writing a secret.  But if you're not single...then sorry, I can't help there.  :-)

Comment: @Primordial Ironically, if I wasn't single, I would have never thought of writing a book :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're worried about jinxing your project, just find something steadfast to motivate you. Who gives a crap what others say? I heard that JK Rowling was rejected around a dozen times before Harry Potter finally broke through, and that story is a reference point for authors now. Don't let sharing your idea with someone else be enough to kick your story underground.

Lying is never a good idea, but maybe you can make it seem like you have another obligation (just something to reduce questioning on why you are alone so much). Or when you're around your friends, make it clear you aren't a loner, be extra engaged, just show them that you're totally good, if you are worried about them being concerned. But I honestly wouldn't worry about it too much.

Just go for it while maintaining a balance. And also - if you really want to take this somewhere, which I'm sure you have the capability to do, why hide from people? You'll have to get it out sometime, right?

Good luck with your story.

Comment: That's a great idea - make it sound like I got another obligation (which is true, because it helps in researching for my novel). Eventually I will let my writing out in the open. My concern was that it's too soon to let anyone know.

Comment: And I am totally inspired by JK Rowling. Her journey is an amazing story!

Answer (score 4):

If your friends ditch you for pursuing a possible second career in writing then you need to find better friends. You don't have to become a loner to write a novel. You can still be extroverted and pursue writing. A matter of fact, being an extrovert can actually help when you seek feedback from your close friends. I wish I had close friends who were willing to read my work. You can collaborate with them or just use your friends as a focus group.

Don't give up.

Comment: If you ever need someone to review your work, I can help. For anyone who reads this.

Comment: Thank you @KaleSlade I might take you up on your offer

Comment: email me at tristanofficial@outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

What I say if some one asks me what I'm doing on the weekend I be really vague.(unless they are asking me out) I say that I probably should work on a story, and act like you aren't too keen on it. For me, it works every time.